# using jQuery ignore: ':hidden:not

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a jQuery validator, and I want to use the `ignore: ':hidden:not` but I want to apply this too all controls which has an ID that contrains "_selecting",

this is what I have so far but not working:

```
sb.AppendLine(@" ignore: ':hidden:not($(""[id*=_selecting]"")',");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by setting the class for the controls as `class="ignore"` and then ignoring them like this :

```
sb.AppendLine(@" ignore: ':hidden:not("".ignore"")',");
```